# How should a verse be translated exactly using Ghanaapaathi?

Tags: vedas

I have seen an example of a verse in GhanaaPaathi as below:

Verse:

> tryambakam yajaamahe sugandhim pushTi vardhanam | urvaarukamiva
>   bandhanaan mrutyor muksheeya maamrutaat ||

The Ghana Patha recitation of this mantra goes as:

> tryambakam yajaamahe yajaamahe tryambakam tryambakam yajaamahe
>   sugandhigm sugandhim yajaamahe tryambakam tryambakam yajaamahe
>   sugandhim | tryambakamititri - ambakam || yajaamahe sugandhigm
>   sugandhim yajaamahe yajaamahe sugandhim pushTivardhanam
>   pushTivardhanagm sugandhim yajaamahe yajaamahe sugandhim
>   pushTivardhanam | sugandhim pushTivardhanam pushTivardhanagm
>   sugandhigm sugandhim pushTivardhanam | sugandhimitisu - gandhim
>   pushTivardhana - mitipushTi - vardhanam || urvaarukamivevorvaaruka -
>   murvaarukamiva bandhanaadbandhanaadi vorvaaruka - murvaarukamiva
>   bandhanaat | iva bandhanaadbandhanaadiveva bandhanaanmrutyo - rmrutyo
>   - rbandhanaadiveva bandhanaanmrutyoho | bandhanaanmrutyo - mrutyorbandhanaadbandhanaanmrutyo - rmuksheeya muksheeya mrutyo –
>   rbandhanaad bandhanaan mrutyor muksheeya | mrutyor muksheeya muksheeya
>   mrutyormrutyo - rmuksheeya maa maa muksheeya rmrutyormrutyo -
>   rmuksheeya maa | muksheeya maa maa muksheeya muksheeya
>   maamrutaadamrutaanmaa muksheeya muksheeya maamrutaat |
>   maamrutaadamrutaanmaa maamrutaat | amrutaadityamrutaat ||

My question is that in the original verse, there is no word by name "sugandhigm". So, how is this included in the GhanaaPaathi version of the verse?

Comment: In the original mantra many pada goes under sandhi to form a new word, but for ghana patha we need the original words(anvaya)